# Swift GoogleMap for SDKでCustomMarkerを実装したいがnilが出てしまい、CustomMarkerのファイルにデータを送れない。

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

#### 前提・実現したいこと

店舗検索アプリの作成過程において、GoogleMap上に店舗情報を表示するCustomMarkerを実装中にエラーが発生してしまいました。

ソースコードにおいてはtitleを代入していますが。"Name"など文字を入力してもこの部分がnilなってしまうため、どうしていいいのか全く見当もつかない状況です。

やりたいこととしては、MapViewController.swiftで取得したデータをGMSMapViewDelegateのmarkerInfoContentsを用いて、MarkerView.swiftにおけるshopname.textに反映させたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

#### 該当のソースコード

MarkerView.swift　　※マップ上マーカーのウィンドウ画面のViewです。xibファイル見た目を作り、IBOutletで繋げてあります。

```
import UIKit

class MarkerView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var infoImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var distanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var shopName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var bgView: UIView!

func setData(title: String, img: UIImage, distance: String) {
    shopName.text = title　//エラーが表示されるのはこの部分です。（Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value）
    infoImg.image = img
    distanceLabel.text = "\(distance)km"
}

}
```

MapViewController.swift　
GMSMapViewDelegateに関する記述を抜粋しています。

// MARK: GOOGLE MAP DELEGATE

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

 guard let customMarkerView = marker.iconView as? CustomMarkerView else { return false }
    let img = customMarkerView.img!
    let customMarker = CustomMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customMarkerWidth, height: customMarkerHeight), image: img, borderColor: UIColor.white, tag: customMarkerView.tag)

    marker.iconView = customMarker

    return false
}
```

下記のfunctionでMarkerView.swiftにデータを送っているつもりです。

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    guard let customMarkerView = marker.iconView as? CustomMarkerView else { return nil }
    let data = previewDemoData[customMarkerView.tag]
    markerView.setData(title: data.title, img: data.cafeImage ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "art-blur-cappuccino-302899"), distance: String(data.distance!))
    return markerView
}




func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
    guard let customMarkerView = marker.iconView as? CustomMarkerView else { return }
    let tag = customMarkerView.tag
    infoTapped(tag: tag)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didCloseInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
    guard let customMarkerView = marker.iconView as? CustomMarkerView else { return }
    let img = customMarkerView.img!
    let customMarker = CustomMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customMarkerWidth, height: customMarkerHeight), image: img, borderColor: UIColor.blue, tag: customMarkerView.tag)
    marker.iconView = customMarker
}
```

```

#### 試したこと

nilになる部分に"Name"などの文字列を代入したのですが、nilになってしまいました。またvibファイルとMarkerView.swiftの接続もやり直してみたり、Objectも変更してみましたが治りませんでした。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Xcode Version 9.4.1 
Swift version 4.1.2 
参考にしたコード
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DefMVYSRbxo

その他、必要な情報などございましたらご教授ください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/145240

Comment: こちらGoogleMapは使ったことがない上、一番肝心な`CustomMarkerView`のコードが示されていない(`MarkerView`クラスと`CustomMarkerView`クラスの関係は???)ので、確度の高いことは言えないんですが、一般に`init(frame:)`のようなイニシャライザでクラスをインスタンス化しても`@IBOutlet`の接続は行われません。storyboard/xib上でのoutletの接続は単なる指示書のようなもので、明示的に「この指示書を使ってインスタンス化しろ」と言う命令を書かなければ、`@IBOutlet`は全部空、つまり`nil`のままなので、`shopName`も`nil`のまま、`nil`なのにそれを無理やり使おうとしている`shopName.text`でエラーになるのは当たり前、と言うことになります。ちなみに「(プログラムのソース)ファイルにデータを送る」という言い方も一般には通じないのでやめた方が良いですね。プログラムのソース(「〜.swift」も)単なる指示書・設計図であり、コンパイルして実行されると「何か」がその指示・設計に従って動いていると言うことになります。Swiftのようなオブジェクト指向言語ではその「何か」として、「インスタンス」というものを強く意識してもらわないといけません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事解決いたしました！

Comment: @Tosh さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。自分のコメントがなにがしかの形で問題解決のお役に立ったのなら幸いです。さて、このサイトはみなさんの経験をQ&A集という形で蓄積することで多くの開発者の皆さんに役立つノウハウ集となることを意図して運営されています。具体的な解決方法をご自身で「回答」として投稿していただけないでしょうか。お時間をいただくことになりますが、是非ともよろしくお願いします。